# Get Rid of all the whitespace under my image using css

Tags: html, css

This is the view from my chrome dev tools :
[image]

The image in my card is supposed to occupy its whole width however it is not occupying and taking this certain amount of whitespace. Trying properties like height 100% and width 100% or object-fit contain/cover is not doing the job.

HTML Code

```
  <div class="cards">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="./assets/shared/ai.svg" alt="" />
            <div class="body">
              <h3>Artificial Intelligence</h3>
              <p>
                Assertively parallel task synergistic <br />
                deliverables after high-quality.
              </p>
              <a href="#">Learn More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <img src="./assets/shared/ai.svg" alt="" />
            <div class="body">
              <h3>Civil Engineering</h3>
              <p>
                Assertively parallel task synergistic <br />
                deliverables after high-quality.
              </p>
              <a href="#">Learn More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <img src="./assets/shared/ai.svg" alt="" />
            <div class="body">
              <h3>Business Studies</h3>
              <p>
                Assertively parallel task synergistic <br />
                deliverables after high-quality.
              </p>
              <a href="#">Learn More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 1421px;
  margin: 0 150px;
}
.cards .card {
  width: 453px;
  height: 512px;
  margin-right: 31px;
}

.cards .card:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.card img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  line-height: 0%;
}
```

Comment: Yupp did not work for both cover and contain.

Comment: is there a possible way you could make a codepen of you recreating the issue? with your code provided i personally can not recreate this issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with your html and CSS. It looks like there might be some other CSS causing those white spaces.

Comment: Look at the calculated tab instead of the styles tab. This is probably part of your SVG file and thus can't be managed with CSS.

Comment: In your screenshot the white space is in the actual SVG. You'll need to adjust the SVG.  It could be related the the SVGs `viewBox` attribute. Test by adding a cool placeholder image like https://www.placecage.com/g/284/196